# Why is this flow (no) complete

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding complete flows. The deffinition of a flow I'm using is that a flow of a vector field defined in a manifold is complete if and only if for any point of the manifold the integral curve through that point can be extended to the entire real line.

I think that I don't fully understand what does it mean to extend it.

For example, I would like to clarify why the vector field $\partial_x$ defined on $\mathbb R$ as a manifold is complete on $\mathbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$ but not on $(0,\infty)$.

The integral curve through the point $x$ is $\phi(t)=t+x$, being $x$ the initial condition. I can't see any non possible extension.

I'm seeing that it can't be complete on the open set because it can't be extended beyond $t=-x$, I don't get that.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I have got some trouble with your $[0, \infty)$ example. That's a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro ..., so?

Comment: AFAIK those things are usually done in manifolds without boundary. It seems strange to me that the vector field $\partial_x$ is complete in $[0, \infty)$. The same incompleteness that you have on $(0, \infty)$ should be there on $[0, \infty)$ too, I think. But I am not an expert at all.